# C++ Dialog launched from C# does not get focus on Opening

Tags: c#, c++, modal-dialog

In my application I am trying to invoke a dialog that is created in c++ from C#.
I have a native c++ dialog and a method to show that dialog in the same assembly itself using `Dialog.DoModal()`.

What I did is, I wrote a CLI wrapper code to invoke the method that will open the dialog. Then I used that wrapper in C#.

When I call the method, it opens the dialog in C++ but it does not get focus. When I try to click on any button on the dialog, the first click for the first time does not work. Then it gets focus and behaves normally from there on.

I tried using stuffs like `SetActiveWindow` and `SetForegroundWindow`. I also tried getting the C# Form handle using `Control.Handle` and passed it to C++ and set it as the parent. The things I tried did not work.

Any ideas?

C++ Code:

```
void CCustomDialogDllFunc::CCustomDialogDllFunc(void)
{
    HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary("CustomDialogResource.dll");
    if(hInst != NULL)
        AfxSetResourceHandle(hInst);
}

bool CCustomDialogDllFunc::DlgDisp(void)
{
    CCustomDialog Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();

    return false;
}
```

CLI Wrapper:

```
WCustomDialogCall::WCustomDialogCall(void)
{
    dialogdllfunc = new CCustomDialogDllFunc;
}

WCustomDialogCall::DlgDisp(void)
{
    dialogdllfunc->DlgDisp();
}
```

C#:

```
void CSMethod()
{

   WCustomDialogCall nativeDialog = new WCustomDialogCall();

   nativeDialog.DlgDisp();

}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to try: Put `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` before Dlg.DoModal()

Comment: I think you would want to set the Form handle as the dialog's Owner, not Parent.